# RegEx for Javascript to allow alphanumeric

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I need to find a reg ex that only allows alphanumeric. i used [^0-9]+/g , but i have always the possibility of the caracter point "."

Comment: if you want alpha**numeric** why are you disallowing 0-9?

Comment: for you case [^0-9]+ means that you can have anything except the numeric characters, so I think this is what you looking for  `^\w+$`.
If you want to allow "." you can use `^[\w\.]+$`

Answer (score 3):

Try :  `^[a-zA-Z0-9\.]*$`

`a-z`  : From a to z - lowercase
`A-Z` :  From A to Z - uppercase
`0-9` : 0 1 2 ......9
`\.` : point
`*` : 0 or multiple
`$` : end of string

Comment: why we are using ^ and $ ?

Answer (score 0):

You are apparently using AngularJS so if you are using this in a input you could use:

```
<input type="text" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9\.]*$/"></input>
```

Here is an simple example.

```html
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="form">
      <input type="text" ng-model="model" id="input" name="input" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9\.]*$/" /><br>
      <hr>
      input valid? = <code>{{form.input.$valid}}</code><br>
      model = <code>{{model}}</code>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Of course you can use this in your angular controller etc:

```
var str = 'u89asdfuijm.';
var res = str.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9\.]*$/);
console.log(res);
```

Make it global or what ever you want. You would need to specify the purpose.

Comment: why we are using ^ and $ ?